# How to read all the elements and child nodes of XML in a list using XDocument?

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net

I have to get all the Entity Source,Entity Target,Property Source  and Property Target  values in list respectively.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Entities>
  <Entity Source="E_cdclient" Target="cd_client">
    <Property Source="KnowledgeItemId" Target="CLIENT_CONTACT_ID"/>
    <Property Source="KnowledgeClientID" Target="CLIENT_CONTACT_ID"/>
  </Entity>
  <Entity Source="E_cdclientsystem" Target="cd_client_system">
    <Property Source="PrimaryKnowledgeItemId" Target="0"/>
    <Property Source="RelatedKnowledgeId" Target="0"/>
  </Entity>
  <Entity Source="E_cdclient_cdclientcontact" Target="cd_client_contact">
    <Property Source="shortdescription" Target="analysis_short_description"/>
    <Property Source="OWNERID" Target="REF_PROJECT_OWNER_ID"/>
  </Entity>
</Entities>
```

I am using XDocument.

```
Public Function ReadXML() As List(Of String)

    'Create the XML Document'
    Dim m_xmld = New XmlDocument()

    'Load the Xml file'
    m_xmld.Load("C:\\MappingFile.xml")

    'Get the list of name nodes'
    Dim m_nodelist = m_xmld.SelectNodes("/Entities/Entity")

    Return list
End Function
```

How can I do this?

How to read all the elements and child nodes of XML in a list using XDocument?

Comment: `XDocument` or `XmlDocument`? Your text says one thing, your code says another. Those two are different things.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Dim lElements = (From el In xml.Descendants("Entity")
                    Select Prop1 = el.Attribute("Prop1").Value, el.Value).ToList
```

This code will give you a List of objects with 2 properties :

- Prop1 : name of your attribute
- Value : Entity node value

You can easily extend that with all the attributes you need.